# SDL video overlay flickers with SDL_Flip

Tags: c++, video, sdl, libav

I use SDL and libav in C++ to draw a video on the screen in Linux. Most of my code for video opening is based on [this tutorial](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/), but I changed some functions that were deprecated. I initialize SDL like this:

```
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
const SDL_VideoInfo * info = SDL_GetVideoInfo();
screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(info->current_w, info->current_h, 0, SDL_SWSURFACE | SDL_FULLSCREEN);
```

I am not going to post the whole code since it is pretty big, but the following shows how I try to display a video overlay. Note that some variables are classmembers from my Video class, like `formatCtx` and `packet`.

```
void Video::GetOverlay(SDL_Overlay * overlay) {
    int frameFinished;
    while (av_read_frame(formatCtx, &packet) >= 0) {
        if (packet.stream_index == videoStream) {
            avcodec_decode_video2(codecCtx, frame, &frameFinished, &packet);
            if (frameFinished) {
                SDL_LockYUVOverlay(overlay);
                AVPicture pict;
                pict.data[0] = overlay->pixels[0];
                pict.data[1] = overlay->pixels[2];
                pict.data[2] = overlay->pixels[1];
                pict.linesize[0] = overlay->pitches[0];
                pict.linesize[1] = overlay->pitches[2];
                pict.linesize[2] = overlay->pitches[1];
                SwsContext * ctx = sws_getContext (codecCtx->width, codecCtx->height, codecCtx->pix_fmt,
                                   codecCtx->width, codecCtx->height,  PIX_FMT_YUV420P, SWS_BICUBIC, NULL, NULL, NULL);
                sws_scale(ctx, frame->data, frame->linesize, 0, codecCtx->height, pict.data, pict.linesize);
                sws_freeContext(ctx);
                SDL_UnlockYUVOverlay(overlay);
                ++frameIndex;
                return;
            }   
        }   
        av_free_packet(&packet);
    }   
}
```

And then in my mainloop:

```
SDL_Overlay * overlay = SDL_CreateYUVOverlay(video->GetWidth(), video->GetHeight(), SDL_YV12_OVERLAY, screen);
while (true) {
    video->GetOverlay(overlay);
    SDL_Rect rect = { 400, 200, video->GetWidth(), video->GetHeight() };
    SDL_DisplayYUVOverlay(overlay, &rect);
    SDL_Flip(screen);
}
```

This works, the video plays but it flickers a lot. Like it tries to draw an image on the same place each frame. When I remove the call to `SDL_Flip(screen)` the video plays fine. Too fast, I haven't worked videotiming out yet, but when I add a temporary `SDL_Delay(10)` it looks pretty good.
But when I remove `SDL_Flip` to show my video, I can't draw anything else on the screen. Both `SDL_BlitSurface` and `SDL_FillRect` fail to draw anything on the screen. I already tried to add `SDL_DOUBLEBUF` to the flags, but this did not change the situation.

I can provide more code if that is needed, but I think the problem is somewhere in the code that I have posted, since everything else is working fine (drawing images, or displaying a video without `SDL_Flip`).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Apparently there are a number of platforms or situations (such as ATI/nVidia driver settings) that can cause vsync to be turned off or not used by SDL_Flip; suggest you search on "sdl_flip vsync" a bit.  You might be hitting any one of these things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still think this isn't the best solution, but I found something that works!
The command `SDL_UpdateRect(screen, 0, 0, 0, 0);` will update the whole screen. If I only update the parts of the screen where no video is drawn, the video won't flicker anymore. I think it might have something to do with SDL_Overlays being handled differently than normal surfaces.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using a SWSURFACE don't use SDL_Flip(screen) use SDL_UpdateRect.  You don't need to set SDL_DOUBLEBUF

http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_UpdateRect

That's what I do and I don't get flicker.

I set my screen like this

```
screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(width, height, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE | SDL_FULLSCREEN);
```

In my main loop I call

```
SDL_UpdateRect(screen, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. The video was still flickering. Are you also drawing a video on a `SDL_Overlay`?

Comment: No, I write to the pixels directly.  Like this: 
memcpy((int*)screen->pixels, image, size*4);

Comment: I'm still using a single thread, but I plan on using multiple threads later on. Do you load your video frame into an image? Or do you just load an image?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean.  I read in a targa file since the format is easy to use and I write directly to screen->pixels.  You can try SDL_BlitSurface instead of memcpy but memcpy is fast enough for me.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, targa is an image format. But I am loading an mp4 video and trying to display the videoframes on a SDL_Overlay. So I think there is a difference between just drawing an image, or drawing videoframes on an overlay, but I am not sure.

Comment: I don't know about SDL_Overlay.  But I generating images (using a ray tracer) at more than 60fps and showing them in real-time with no flicker.  I copy to the new image to the pixel buffer and do SDL_Update each frame.

Comment: anyway, since I have not used SDL_Overlay I'm not sure I can help you. I would check out http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_Overlay . It appears to have an example on how to use it using e.g. memcpy.

Comment: I will check that link later today and update my post if I have found a working solution. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You should use double buffering to prevent flickering.

```
screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(info->current_w, info->current_h, 0, SDL_SWSURFACE | SDL_FULLSCREEN | SDL_DOUBLEBUF);
```

Comment: I should have mentioned this before, but I tried this already but it had no effect, the video still flickers.